# New-CimSession with using WMI protocol and Kerberos authentication

Tags: powershell, wmi, kerberos, cim

My app remotely collects some info from windows machines and now I wanna try to use CimSession with DCOM protocol and Kerberos authentication instead of classic WMI commands like Get-WmiObject and etc.

I try to create a session like these:

```
$Cim_SessionOption = New-CimSessionOption -Protocol Dcom 
$CimSession = New-CimSession -ComputerName $ComputerHost -Credential $cred -Authentication Kerberos -SessionOption $Cim_SessionOption
```

But it receive an error: New-CimSession : The RPC server is unavailable

Computers are domain members, the user has all needed permissions, I tried to use DNS name and IP in -ComputerName parameter.

If i just create a session without specifying an Authentication parameter all works fine:

```
$Cim_SessionOption = New-CimSessionOption -Protocol Dcom 
$CimSession = New-CimSession -ComputerName $ComputerHost -Credential $cred -SessionOption $Cim_SessionOption
```

Output is:

```
Id           : 1
Name         : CimSession1
InstanceId   : f8cdcbdf-377a-49d7-907e-4c909815a325
ComputerName : ComputerName
Protocol     : DCOM
```

What is wrong with Kerberos here?

Comment: There are many authentication methods like Window Credentials, Kerberos, and OAUTH2.  The client can only connect with a method that the server uses.  You are missing the -Authentication option.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/new-cimsession?view=powershell-7.4

Comment: Furthermore look over https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/new-cimsessionoption?view=powershell-7.4#-impersonation as you might need to play with `-impersonation` parameter using the dcom protocol with that command.

Comment: If you have remote powershell enabled, you can use the default wsman protocol.

Comment: Yes, WinRM works fine with kerberos, but i have to use DCOM\WMI here

Comment: Which PowerShell version are you using? Do the old Get-Wmi cmdlets work properly?